# How can I prove Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are real?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I know it is convention to taken Clebsch-Gordan $\color{blue}{<j_1,j_2;m_1,m_2|j_1,j_2;j,m>}$coefficients are real.If I want to make proof it's reality from any  physical defination in backward then how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmmm...  I don't think there is a *proof* as such, since it's simply a choice of phase for the individual highest weight states $|j,j\rangle$ states in the decomposition . It would be  like asking for a proof that the coefficients $\sqrt{j(j+1)-m(m-1)}$ in the action of the ladder operator $J_-$  are real. This latter reality is merely  a choice of phase for the states $|j,m\rangle$ relative to that of $|j,j\rangle$.

Comment: In this case, the relevant proof would be to show that it is always possible to choose the phase so that the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are real.